# What are these files in analyse apk?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

[image]

these files weren't in my project but were auto included in **analyze apk**?

[image]

what are these **a** and **b** packages which consumed more space?

Comment: Its look like reverse engineering apk files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe those are obfuscated classes.

> While obfuscation does not remove code from your app, significant size savings can be seen in apps with DEX files that index many classes, methods, and fields. However, as obfuscation renames different parts of your code, certain tasks, such as inspecting stack traces, require additional tools

You can get more info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#obfuscate)